How to remotely connect to k8s through @kubernates/client-node?
I dev k8s client in macos(192.168.1.6), and the k8s(k3s) deploy in virtual machine of  master(192.168.100.100)
The docs https://github.com/kubernetes-client/javascript?tab=readme-ov-file#create-a-cluster-configuration-programatically
const k8s = require('@kubernetes/client-node');

const cluster = {
    name: 'my-server',
    server: 'http://server.com',
};

const user = {
    name: 'my-user',
    password: 'some-password',
};

const context = {
    name: 'my-context',
    user: user.name,
    cluster: cluster.name,
};

const kc = new k8s.KubeConfig();
kc.loadFromOptions({
    clusters: [cluster],
    users: [user],
    contexts: [context],
    currentContext: context.name,
});
const k8sApi = kc.makeApiClient(k8s.CoreV1Api);

Please forgive me for just starting out with k8s, i don't know how to get the server and password.

With this code, the client is creating/instantiating a context equivalent to what you should have in the KUBECONFIG file that you're using to access k3s using e.g. kubectl.
See Config.
Specifically:

cluster as NamedCluster
user as NamedAuthInfo
context as NamedContext

Aside: It's curious that the Node.js SDK doesn't specify current-context
If you're using username|password to authenticate to k3s, then you should be able to find the relevant entries in the KUBECONFIG file (usually ${HOME}/.kube/config) but this is unlikely.
It is more common to see either:

client certificates
tokens
ExecConfig to acquire|refresh tokens

If your cluster uses client certificates, you can reflect the entries in the KUBECONFIG as the user in your code (see AuthInfo for appropriate properties).
If your cluster uses tokens or ExecConfig, you've more to do as you need a way to acquire and refresh tokens.
This answer on Stack overflow for k3s may be helpful.
